# unload externally loaded swf

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash

In my app, I have loaded some external swf files. It's a game files so for avoiding sandbox error I use the follwing code:

```
var file:File = File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath("myFilePath");
var toLoadUrl = file.url;
var myUrl:URLRequest;
myUrl = new URLRequest(toLoadUrl);
var inFileStream:FileStream = new FileStream(); 
inFileStream.open(file, FileMode.READ); 
var swfBytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
inFileStream.readBytes(swfBytes);
inFileStream.close();

var loaderContext:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext(false, ApplicationDomain.currentDomain);

loaderContext.allowLoadBytesCodeExecution = true;
loaderContext.allowCodeImport = true;
myLoader = new Loader();

myLoader.loadBytes(swfBytes, loaderContext);
//myLoader.load(myUrl, loaderContext);

myLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, LoadComplete_swf);
myLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, loop, false, 0, true);
myLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR,loadingError);
```

And to unload the file, I've used:

```
if(myLoader)
{
    trace("Unloaded");
    myLoader.unloadAndStop(true);
    myLoader.unload();
}
while(MovieClip(root).holder.numChildren > 0)
{
    var item:DisplayObject = MovieClip(root).holder.removeChildAt(0);
    trace("Removed");
}
if(contains(myLoader))
{
    trace("Remove child");
    removeChild(myLoader);
}
```

It works but only for one time. After that It keeps stacking all the files even the codes to remove it has been executed. I can still hear the sounds and the codes from the swf files are still running. Is there any problem with the above code? How do I completely remove the loaded files? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Generally you do it in a right way, but... If your loaded content has a full access to parent content, it is not impossible that you forget to remove certain objects (sprites or event listeners) attached outside **myLoader**, and the whole thing is not unloaded. Also, I never tried it with active content, only with libraries without internal scripts so there could be things I'm not aware of. BTW, you remove children from the wrong container in your script.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I don't think there's anything left to remove. I even set swfContent a movieclip which holds the data to null. And removing and unloading did work but only for one time. I even tried to manually collect the garbage but it also didn't work.

Comment: GC is not a panacea, it removes things that **already** accessible via AS# means. I think you need to review the sources of loaded content and properly destroys everything instantiated, unsubscribe all events etc. Or/and maybe isolate it from main app ApplicationDomain. Or/and maybe try loading it regularly , not from bytes.

Comment: If i load it regularly, it works but throws sandbox error. Do I need to destroy everything from external swf manually? The problem is it's gonna be different types of games using different types of methods and it's difficult for me track everything inside external swf files. How to isolate if from main app ApplicationDomain?

Comment: **var loaderContext:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext(false, new ApplicationDomain(null));** http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/LoaderContext.html#applicationDomain

Comment: Thanks a lot. It seems to be working. So far it hasn't shown any sandbox error and it seems everythings got removed.